# Get the specific simple name of a generic type in Scala

Tags: generics, scala

Is it possible to get the type name of a generic class in Scala? I know this isn't possible in Java with type erasure, but I was hoping that Scala would be a different case.

Currently I have to do something similar to this:

```
trait Model
case class User(id: String) extends Model

def fromMap[M<:Model : Manifest](data: Map[String, String], modelType: String) = {
  modelType match {
    case "user" => User(data.get("id").get)
  }
}

val user = fromMap[User](Map("id" -> "id1"), "user")
```

Obviously it would be easier if I could work out "user" without having to have it passed in.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Scala compiles to Java bytecode, so at run time it has to work under the constraints of the the Java VM -- which includes that only erased types exist at runtime.

Comment: I made some edit to what I believe were simple mistakes in your code. Change back if I'm wrong

Comment: Cheers, you were nearly right. User should have extended Model, but the modelType is supposed to be a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Class name can be retrieved from a Manifest (or a ClassManifest) with `manifest.erasure.getName` (erasure is the Class instance). For instance

```
def className[A : ClassManifest] = classManifest[A].erasure.getName
```

**Edit** : Seen Derek's answer, which makes this stuff with erasure.getName look rather stupid. I didn't consider toString. Still I hope what follows may be of interest

The difference between using `ClassManifest` and `Manifest` is that in the `Manifest` for a generic class, the type parameter are guaranteed to be available, while they are best effort in `ClassManifest` (compare signatures of `typeParameters` in both classes). The drawback of this guarantee is that a `Manifest` might not be implicitly available where a `ClassManifest` would be.

Have you considered using typeclasses instead?

```
trait BuilderFromMap[A] {def build(data: Map[String, String]): A} 
  // or better, return Option[A], accounting for possible failure
object User {
   implicit val Builder extends BuilderFromMap[User] {...}
}
def fromMap[A](data: Map[String, String])(implicit builder: BuilderFromMap[A])
  = builder.build(data)
```

This way, calls to `fromMap` will compile only if a `Builder` is available for this particular class, rather than fail with a `MatchError`.

Comment: Yeah, that's about an order of magnitude better than what I trucked out :)

Comment: @Derek Pity you removed your answer, while I like typeclasses better, it was quite nice as a fix of the OP code.

Comment: Updating for Scala 2.11.7: `erasure` being deprecated, the right terms would now be `m.runtimeClass.getName`.

Comment: deprecated. use scala.reflect.classTag[T].runtimeClass.getName

Answer (score 12):

For those of you coming to this question from a world with Scala 2.12.x or 2.13.x, `ClassTag[T]` is the preferred way to do this.

```
import scala.reflect._ 

trait Model 
case class User(id: String) extends Model 

def fromMap[M <: Model : ClassTag](data: Map[String, String]) = {
  val modelType = implicitly[ClassTag[M]].runtimeClass.getSimpleName
  modelType match {
    case "User" => User(data("id"))
  }
} 

val user = fromMap[User](Map("id" -> "id1"))
```

Answer (score 5):

For Scala 2.11, following code works:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{typeOf, TypeTag}

def name[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toString

def fullName[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.fullName
```

Execution example:

```
scala> name[String]
res5: String = String

scala> fullName[String]
res6: String = java.lang.String
```

Ref:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/scala-reflect/index.html

Comment: `def f[T](v: T) = name[T]`, compilation fails with `No TypeTag available for T`

Comment: `def f[T: TypeTag](v: T) = name[T]` works. We need the TypeTag implicit parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (but I had to edit your code in order to guess what you wanted):

```
trait Model
case class User(id: String) extends Model

object Main extends App {
  def fromMap[M <: Model](data: Map[String, String])(implicit m: reflect.Manifest[M]): Model = {
    m.toString match {
      case "User" => User(data.get("id").get)
    }
  }

  val user = fromMap[User](Map("id" -> "id1"))
  println(user)
}
```

But based on the trouble I had with it, I'm sure someone could do something better :)